# Wake-On-LAN without motherboard support

Tags: power, wake-on-lan

I have an old desktop which I want to turn into a home server. Unfortunately its motherboard ([MSI K9N6SGM-V](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6SGMV__K9N6PGMFI__K9N6PGMF.html#/?div=Detail)) does not support Wake-on-LAN functionality.

I don't really know how power supply works in Wake-on-LAN scenario. From [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Hardware_requirements) I couldn't answer the following question: if I'll get a [PCI NIC card with Wake-on-LAN](http://www.ebay.com/itm/330726933665) and connect it with a corresponding 3-pin cable to the motherboard - is it enough then to have Wake-on-LAN enabled? Or the motherboard still needs to support WOL internally?

In case this NIC solution doesn't work, what are the other options to enable WON?

P.S.
I've seen [DIY](http://www.domstyle.net/blog/2013/02/18/dropping-dropbox-hardware-hacking/) solutions out there involving some mobile router re-assembly. Its rather complicated for me, maybe something simpler could be recommended :)

---

There is a broader approach to my question: [Wake on LAN Alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/329158/wake-on-lan-alternatives)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the motherboard needs to support WOL, and if the motherboard doesn't have WOL support then it won't have the (legacy) 3-pin WOL cable connector of which you speak.

If you want WOL get a motherboard with WOL, that's the easiest/only real way to get it.

Comment: Indeed, I was just looking at motherboard and couldn't find any suitable 3-pin slots. I guess buying new one is the simplest solution.